# Sklearn will not run/compile due to numpy errors

Tags: numpy, flask, scikit-learn

I would not be posting this question if I had not researched this problem thoroughly. I run `python server.py` (it uses sklearn). Which gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 34, in <module>
    from lotusApp.lotus import lotus
  File "/Users/natumyers/Desktop/.dev/qq/lotusApp/lotus.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

I next do everything I can, nothing helps.

I ran:

```
sudo -H pip uninstall numpy
sudo -H pip uninstall pandas

sudo -H pip install numpy
sudo -H pip install pandas
```

All which give me errors such as `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:`

I try `sudo -H easy_install --upgrade numpy`

I get a list of errors like

```
_configtest.c:13:5: note: 'ctanl' is a builtin with type '_Complex long double (_Complex long double)'
_configtest.c:14:5: warning: incompatible redeclaration of library function 'cpowl' [-Wincompatible-library-redeclaration]
int cpowl (void);
    ^
```

Edit: Perhaps part of the issue was that I wasn't running the virtual environment. So I get that going, and when I type `python server.py`, I get error:

```
from sklearn import datasets
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

`sudo -H pip install -U scikit-learn` Doesn't install because of another error....

Comment: Don't do sudo, a dedicated virualenv is nearly always preferrable.

Comment: I fixed it. I just used pip3/python 3. P2 was a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using depreciated python. I updated everything to python 3, and used `pip3`.